# Difference between declaring static object and pointer to static object

Tags: c++, static-members

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class First{
        public:
        void fun()
        {
            cout<<"base fun called\n";
        }
    };

    class Second{
        public:
        static First x; //Line 1
        static First *y; //Line 2
    };

    First Second::x; //Line 3

    First* Second::y; //Line 4

    int main()
    {
        Second::x.fun();
        Second::y->fun();
        return 0;
    }
```

Line 1 and Line 2 are declarations and Line 3 and Line 4 are definitions, this I have understood from some other stackoverflow posts about static members.

Q1. Why we have to define static objects like this ? (Line 3 and line 4)

Q2. Whats difference between x and y?(Line 1 and Line 2)

Q3. Where is the memory allocated for x and y objects ?(Line 3 and Line 4)

Comment: You should really ask one question at a time.

Comment: Are you really asking what's the difference between an object and a pointer to an object? Static doesn't change that at all. And there is no pointer to a static object. There is a static pointer to an object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `y` is a [*pointer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29) (not an object - a pointer is not the same as the object it could point to). Since it is `static`, it gets initialized with `nullptr`, unless you *explicitly* define it initialized to something else (e.g. have some `First z;` object and define `First* Second::y= &z;`).
So `Second::y->fun();` is dereferencing a null pointer, and that is [**undefined behavior**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You really should be [very scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

We cannot answer all your questions here (an entire book would be needed, and the notion of pointer and its [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29) is difficult to explain, and related to [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing); read also about [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space)). So take a few weeks to read some good book like [Programming - Principles and Practice Using C++](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/); you probably will benefit by also reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) & [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms) (even if neither is about C++; however both are related to programming, which is [difficult to learn](http://norvig.com/21-days.html)).

See also some good [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site, it gives a short explanation about [`static` class members](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).

Notice that using raw pointers is often (but not always) a bad smell in genuine C++11. You probably should consider having [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), but YMMV.

Comment: Technically, a pointer is also itself an object.

Comment: A C++ smart pointer is an object, but not a C++ raw pointer. You cannot apply any member function `fun` to `y` as `y.fun();`

Comment: 1.8 The C++ Object Model: _an object is a region of storage_ - a pointer also requires storage. The ability to call member functions is not what defines an object. The standard clearly defines pointers, and eg `int` variables, as objects (just as in C).

Comment: @ davmac - The standard doesn't "clearly define pointers" as objects - "The following entities are not objects: value, reference,.., and this" (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object). But "this’ pointer is a constant pointer that holds the memory address of the current object.

Comment: @SChepurin a pointer in a variable is an object. This discussion is referring to OP's question, and this answer, which states that "your `y` is a pointer (not an object)". However, `y` is an object, despite also being a pointer. My comment above is intended to refer to pointer variables, not pointer values. (Also, cppreference.com is not the standard).

Comment: @davmac - I understand, and that happens just because the standard doesn't clearly define pointers. And now we discuss raw pointers, smart pointers, "this" pointer, pointer variables and pointer values. Some  - are objects, some - are not.

Comment: @SChepurin The standard defines pointers (in 8.3.1 "Pointers"). All raw pointers which occupy storage are objects. In the context of this question, the pointer designated by `y` is clearly an object. That pointers might not be objects is not something that the standard allows for, from my reading ("pointer" is the object, "pointer value" is its value). The "`this` is not an object" claim is not actually stated in the standard at all. (That `this` is a prvalue does not require that it does not refer to a value stored in an object.) If part of the actual standard contradicts, feel free to quote.

Comment: My point is that a pointer is not the same as the object it is pointing to (if any).

Comment: @SChepurin: The standard does clearly define lvalue pointers as "objects". In C++ terminology "variable", "object" and "data lvalue" are virtually synonymous concepts. `this` pointer is not an lvalue, which is why it is not an object. All lvalues of pointer type are objects.

Comment: @AnT - "The standard does clearly define lvalue pointers as "objects". - Yes. And that is exactly what i wanted to say: The person has to correctly interpret the standard to come to conclusion that "in C++ terminology" "this pointer is not an lvalue, which is why it is not an object".

Comment: @SChepurin is the problem the missing "variables" in the sentence? "The standard clearly defines pointer _variables_, and eg int variables, as objects (just as in C)" - is how it was intended to be read. I had thought this was clear from context (it's clearly talking about variables) and ongoing discussion. I think that whether pointer values (including `this`) are or are not objects is besides the point.

Comment: @davmac - "is the problem the missing "variables" in the sentence?" - Of course this matters. And also, i would avoid the sentence - "the standard clearly defines".

Comment: @SChepurin in that case, you have interpreted my comment in the wrong context, as I say. 'i would avoid the sentence - "the standard clearly defines"' - we'll have to agree to disagree on that.

Comment: @davmac - Finally, defined clearly enough to disagree. :)

Comment: @davmac the standard defines objects by enumerating ways in which they are created (1.8[intro.object]). The expression `this` is not on that list. In non-lawyerese, `this` has no address, and no object identity, it's just a value. Pointer variables (created by definitions, which is the first item on that list) are, of course, objects.

Comment: @Cubbi this is getting out of hand. There is no reason why the value of `this` cannot be stored in a temporary object, which 1.8 allows ("An object is created ... by the implementation (12.2) when needed|). But that's beside the point; the answer says "Your y is a pointer (not an object ...)" but `y` by definition defines an object (which holds a pointer value) according to the same section 1.8. Pointer variables represent objects. Whether `this` is an object or not has no bearing on the answer or question and so does not bear discussing here.

Answer (score 4):

1) Because when the objects of a class are created, there will be no memory allocated for theirs static members - so lines 1&2 *declare* that there should be such members, but lines 3&4 *define* where the memory should be allocated.

2) There is literally no big difference - both `x` and `y` are just members of class `Second`, but of different type. `x` is of type `First` and its size equals to sum of `First` members. `y` is of type `First*` - its size depends on a size of pointer used in a particular compilator.

3) There is already a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270519/5232529) about memory allocation for static members. The most common implementation is to use [data segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) of a program.

Answer (score 2):

**Q1**
When you write a `class` statement it is usually the declaration. No actual data members are allocated anywhere. For non-static members, the definition takes place upon instantiation, when the constructor is being called.
However, static members are not related to instantiation. They should be allocated once, and you should decide where. This is the reason for the actual definition. That file (when compiled) will be responsible to actually allocate those members.

That actually answers **Q3** as well. As for **Q2**, I am not sure what is the exact question.